# jQuery,sending password via ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have registration box,and I want users to register via ajax.
Is it safe to send password via jquery ajax?
If not,can someone explain what to do to secure password data,any example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to clarify, there is not a 100% secure method to send any kind of data with Ajax, or even a normal POST.

A good practice is to use SSL/TLS Certificates, if you have a good SSL/TLS certificate nobody can sniff out the password from observing your network traffic.

Unfortunately these services are not free. (*)

If you don't want to pay for something like that and you're building a Sign Up / Log In you can simply use OpenAuth or OpenID and let people join using Social Networks avoiding many security steps both Client and Server side.

*: As suggested by **Ivan Venediktov**, you can now get a free SSL certificate by following this [LINK](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: I will need to check this.Tnx

Comment: I don't think this said anything about security

Comment: It is not useful, if you have firebug, its display username and password. Any user with knowledge of firebug or something can see your request from console and can misuse the code

Comment: @KameshJungi, surely the username and password you see in console is your own username and password, not other people's. Can you explian your theory? I think you're the only person that can see your password in console. It's only unsafe if you leave your computer unattended on the same page, as somebody could access console and read the data, or if you don't use SSL somebody could sniff the data elsewhere. Usually with AJAX logins, the page would have refreshed if the login was successful and the POST info wouldn't be available. To me, this appears to be safe, if using SSL.

Comment: @JPCF: What's different between this AJAX post and a normal post that allows it to be sniffed? Both are not secure if not using SSL.

Comment: Just to correct Andrea, you can get a free SSL certificate by using https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: @IvanVenediktov This question / answer is more than 8 years old... Many things are changed and I wont to keep it updated every 6 months since technology grow quickly. It would be better to look after to newer questions and answers. This will be the last time I update this answer. Cheers

Comment: Lets Encrypt has been around for quite some time. I agree SSL is going to be the best solution. However I disagree that there is no secure method to send a password from a client to a server. If a client encrypts with a public key it is secure even if a man in the middle occurs as only the receiving server would have the private key.

Answer (score 23):

Make sure that you're sending it via POST and use SSL rather than plain old http and you should be fine. Sending it via AJAX does not make it less safe than a regular post.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796044/383744) (and another discussion [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17039/16114)) for a more in depth explanation, but the jist of it is that the request you're making, and the information that is transmitted over the wire is fundamentally the same whether its an AJAX request or form submit.

Comment: I want to add that the entire HTTP request, whether POST or GET is encrypted over an HTTPS connection.  Neither is more secure than the other, with the main exception (inapplicable here b/c of ajax) being that URL's may be seen in a users address bar history -- and you may not want a password saved in the user's history.

Comment: Can you post some relevant links or more information about the same .

Comment: @SiddharthSharma Updated with some links to other questions on the network.

Comment: @user147 this should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using HTTPS ([SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL)) (and please do for anything that needs to be secure) then yes an AJAX request is no more or less safe than a full postback to the server.

Answer (score 5):

It's just as safe/unsafe as sending the password via a full post-back. You need to use an encrypted connection in order for it to be safe(r). Use SSL (https://).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go one step further with security.
You don't even need to collect the users password, you can generate a hash (with salt!) on the client side with something like this http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html then you never see the password, only the hash

The only issue with this is javascript is required. you can easily do a fallback however

Comment: So what if a man in the middle snoops the hash? Wouldn't he still be able to log on?

Comment: yes, but you don't leak the password. 
Another was is sending a unique salt for each login attempt, you generate a hash on the client using the password+unique salt. But then you are just getting overly complex

Comment: But since you're also sending the web page, won't the man in the middle also know the encryption method, thus being able to crack it very easily? I mean, couldn't the salt also easily be intercepted too, if he already could snoop what the client sends?

Comment: why go to all that effort for a MITM attack? just grab the session cookie :)

Comment: Because FYTW. I gather that's why most hackers do it. That or money. It doesn't really matter, because it's a real risk. Anyway, what makes cookies safer than a regular POST? And aren't really cookie information also sent by the very same POST protocol?