# HOw to create meter to check password strength in php?

Tags: php, javascript, function

As we know that we can call any function of Javascript
to control's event like onblur() or onclick() etc.

but ,, i don't want to use javascript...is there another way to call php function

actually i want to check password strength whater it is weak, average or strong..using PHP.

Comment: You could have them submit the page, and have your function run - but you can't have it do it client side without javascript

Comment: what are your criteria for password strength?

Comment: Why don't you want to use JavaScript? It's basically the only way to have a dynamic password meter. You can use PHP to submit an HTML form as a POST parameter and give you the password strength, but that's rather unsafe (anyone reading your traffic can see the password in plaintext unless you specifically encrypt the contents of the POST body or use HTTPS).

Comment: Reference implementation: http://www.passwordmeter.com/

Comment: You can probably use VBScript in a small number of browsers. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about password meters is that they need to work dynamically. The only way I can think of you using a PHP function to dynamically determine the strength for a password that is SAFE, is to send a request through an AJAX POST with SSL (HTTPS).

[Check out this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101440/jquery-sending-password-via-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and pwdMeter include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pwdMeter.js"></script>
```

**jQuery to fire a call to plugin:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#password").pwdMeter();

    });
</script>
```

**This code call .pwdMeter(); function on document ready trigger.**

HTML Code:

```
<div id="grid">
  <input type="password" id="password">
  <span id="pwdMeter" class="neutral"></span>
</div>
```

**It will show textbox to enter password and when you enter something in password box it shows you strength in empty span.**

```
<style>
.veryweak{
color:#B40404;
}

.weak{
color:#DF7401;
}

.medium{
color:#FFFF00;
}

.strong{
color:#9AFE2E;
}

.verystrong{
color:#0B610B;
}
</style>
```