# Javascript hide/show function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

Im trying to create a login/register system/menu for a html5/js game im programming.

At the moment i have set up the html page with the different divs ill be using for the menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TBG basic structure</title>
<script src="JS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<section id="wrapper">
<header>
    <h1><img src="images/title.png" width="467" height="184"/></h1>

</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leagues</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<article id="container">
    <div id="load-new">
        <p>LOAD/NEW</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reg">
        <p>REGISTER</p>
    </div>
    <div id="login">
        <p>LOGIN</p>
    </div>
    <div id="access">
        <p>ACCESS</p>
        <button id="login-but" onclick="login2()">Login</button>
        <button id="reg-but" onclick="register()">Register</button>
    </div>
    <canvas id="TBG" width="640" height="416">
        Please use a more up to date browser
    </canvas>
    <div id="GUI">
        <div id="health">
            <p><img src="images/heart.png"/>: <span class="gameHealth"></span></p>
            </div>
        <div id="energy">
            <p><img src="images/energy.png"/>: <span class="gameEnergy"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="table_container"></div>
    </div>
</article>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically i want to use javascript/jquery to hide show the correct parts of the menu due to users decisions.

So the first div the user will see is the access div which will give the user 2 options, "login" or "register" as you can see with the buttons within the access div above.

Basically i want my JS to hide the access div when one of the buttons are pressed and then either show the login div or reg div depending on which button the user pressed.

Here is the Js i have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var loadScr = $("#load-new");
var regScr = $("#reg");
var loginScr = $("#login");
var accessScr = $("#access");

    loadScr.hide();
    regScr.hide();
    loginScr.hide();

    function login()
    {
        accessScr.hide();
        loginScr.show();
    }

    function register()
    {
        accessScr.hide();
        regScr.show();
    }

});
```

It seems as though the onclick function of the buttons isnt interacting with the JS. i know this because i placed an alert which just said test in the login function which is called when the user clicks login button but i had no response back.

Am i doing something rather silly?

Thanks

Comment: you called it login2() in your onclick

Comment: It's also better to use `_` instead of `-` in your `#ids`

Comment: Also try using Unobtrusive Javascript on your HTML, `$("#login-but").on("click",function() { login(); });` instead of `<button onclick='login();' />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is add `type="button"` to your `<button>` elements. Your page might be reloading because some browsers treat `<button>` elements as `type="submit"` by default. Also, "-" is not a valid character in your `id` attributes, so I've replaced it with a "_".

```
<button id="login_but" type="button">Login</button>
<button id="reg_but" type="button">Register</button>
```

I also removed the `onclick` attributes from your buttons, because it would be better to assign the click events programmatically (an "unobtrusive" JavaScript technique). Next, I would move the two functions out of the document-ready, and forget about keeping references to the elements. Using ID selectors with jQuery is incredibly fast. Your JS should now look like:

```
function login()
{
    $('#access').hide();
    $('#login').show();
}

function register()
{
    $('#access').hide();
    $('#reg').show();
}

$(function() {

    $('#login_but').click(login);
    $('#reg_but').click(register);

    $('#load-new').hide();
    $('#reg').hide();
    $('#login').hide();

});
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly and i believe i understand all your reasons! so thankyou, one question though, why move the login ad register functions out of doc ready?? Thanks

Comment: @TomBurman: If you don't move them out of the document-ready section, nothing outside of that scope will have access to them. You *could* leave them in there, but you might find other reasons to invoke those outside of the `click` events.

Comment: I might add that I would probably even wrap up the two functions in their own module (http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern).

Comment: Ok thanks!! One more question, on my login div, when you user fills in the form i need to run a php script to check details etc i then need if succesfull the login div to be hidden and the load div to be shown, whats the best way of doing this? because i am confusing myself over the situation haha

Comment: @Tom: Are you familiar with AJAX requests? You will need to POST the information to the server with an AJAX request and handle the response (success or error) with their respective callback functions. Check the API documentation for [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/);

Comment: ok so you think i should save the form data into JS variables then use ajax to forward the details on to the php script?

Comment: @TomBurman: Yep. Sometimes this can be as easy as setting the `data` property in the `$.ajax({})` options to `$('#myFormId').serialize()`;

Comment: Wouldnt this way make passwords etc unsecure because they will have to first be stored in a js var and the parsed to php to be encrypted?

Comment: @TomBurman: It isn't any less safe than simply posting the page back to the server. See this thread for an example of what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101440/jquery-sending-password-via-ajax