# Auth validation in AJAX Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am a bit confused with AJAX in Laravel. I am quite new in Laravel and OOP and OOP framework and I have no idea how to do AJAX requests. I read several tutorial over the web but all are different and it looks complicated.

I installed Laravel 5.2, I setup the auth using `php artisan make:auth`, I moved the register form from `/register` to `/`.

I made a small jQuery snippet for the mandatory fields, but I would like to do AJAX validation for each field (name, email, password, password_confirm). Laravel provides the validation rules, and I would like to reuse them.

I have no idea how to do it...

How does it work? A concrete example would be nice and help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel validator to check the mandatory fields.
But this validation you can use it only in the backend side, not frontend.

For example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->messages(), 500);
    }
}
```

You have a similar example in the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Answer (score 0):

Make your route, `/validate`, setting your controller in the `routes.php` file,  then you can send the data to a function in a controller:

```
public function validate(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:50',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required' 
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->messages(), 500);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['result' => 'OK'], 200);
    }

}
```

you can send the data by your client side, using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ROOT_URL+'/validate',
    method: 'POST',
    data: data_collected
}).then(function(){
    alert('Everything OK');
    //Do your stuff
}, function(data){
    //showing errors
    alert(data);    
});
```

If you send the password without encrypt is highly recommend that you have SSL certificate to send information over https protocol, if not, make sure to do safe the sending of data.

Reference: 
[jQuery,sending password via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101440/jquery-sending-password-via-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget csrf token.

its your head meta;

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
```

its your all ajax request,

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

another choise

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'news/', 'users/' // a.com/news/1
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provide [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection) Token for security reason.

If you want to use AJAX in laravel, You must pass CSRF token with Data.
If you don't provide CSRF Token and call AJAX, It will throw CSRF Token mismatch Exception.

You should read this :
https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection